# Train arrival time probability

Tags: probability

> A local train should arrive at 13.03. The late arrival
>   time is a random variable which distributes uniformly over the
>   interval (−2, 8) (minute as the unit). Find the probability that the
>   train arrives:
>
> a) later than at 13.07

My attempt(s): $P(4 ≤ X ≤ 8) = P(X ≤ 8) - P(X ≤ 4) =
 P\frac{8-(-2)}{8-(-2)}-P\frac{4-(-2)}{8-(-2)}  =\frac{10}{10}-\frac{6}{10} =\frac{4}{10}$

or should it be instead

$P(X ≤ 4) = P\frac{4-(-2)}{8-(-2)} =\frac{6}{10} =\frac{3}{5}$

It's my first probability class and I'm a bit confused with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the random variable (late arrival time) $X$ is uniformly distributed over $-2$ to $8$, your probability density function is 
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{8-(-2)} &\mbox{ if } -2 \leq x\leq 8, \\ 
0 &\mbox{ otherwise}. 
\end{cases} 
$$
Since you have to find the probability that the train arrives later than $13.07$, which is being late $4$ minutes or more, you have to find 
$$
P(X\geq 4) = \int_4^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_4^8 \frac{1}{10}dx = \frac{1}{10}4 = \frac{2}{5} = \boxed{0.40}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.